# React-Semantic-UI Cards with Pinterest Layout

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui in React (semantic-ui-react) to display cards. I need a pinterest style layout, where cards will have different heights based on the amount of text present.

```
 ....
<Card.Content>
  <Card.Header className="textheader">
       <b>{this.props.tittle}</b>
  </Card.Header>
  </Card.Content>
            <CardsExtra question="My Question goes here"/>
....
```

What I want is the height of the card should increase for a question with more words in . Currently, all cards take the same height of the one with the maximum height (max number of words in question).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for a pinterest-like layout. It is, in my opinion, the best 'grid layout' library. As to the different heights, this is possible with Masonry.

As to the details of how to do it, you should read the Masonry docs and then try it yourself first. If you still have problems you can create a question for the exact problem or update this one.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, a solution provided by cdog can be found [here](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3353#issuecomment-244058579). Essentially, it is a CSS hack to Semantic UI with the CSS below.

```
.masonry.grid {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .masonry.grid {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
       -moz-column-gap: 0;
            column-gap: 0;
  }

  .ui.doubling.masonry.grid[class*="three column"] > .column {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .masonry.grid {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
       -moz-column-count: 3;
            column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

It works and the result looks promising
http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/oj4ew4Le/embedded/result

The only downside of the pure CSS solution is that the order of the content has to be from top to bottom, then left to right, not left to right, then top to bottom.

For the alternative ordering option, Masonry or similar JS library seems to be required. See the original post in GitHub for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without anything special. Don't put the cards in a card group. Instead, make however many columns you want, and put the cards in each column as desired. Try the snippet below:

```
<Grid columns={3} stretched>
  <Grid.Column>
    <Card style={{ height: '30px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '55px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '70px' }} />
  </Grid.Column>
  <Grid.Column>
    <Card style={{ height: '55px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '30px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '70px' }} />
  </Grid.Column>
  <Grid.Column>
    <Card style={{ height: '55px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '70px' }} />
    <Card style={{ height: '30px' }} />
  </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```